# iOS modify video frame by frame on iPhone (to add CC)

Tags: iphone, ios, video, frame

I am interested in adding text (in close captioned style) to an existing video on the iPhone.  Some solutions to this on stackoverflow suggest to add a transparent UIView to overlay the video.  That is all good, but, I cannot save that as a "new and modified video".

The only solution that I see is to take the text, take a single frame from the video, add the text to the frame, and push the modified frame with text back into the video, replacing the original frame in the video.

Does anyone know how to take a frame out of the video, (I think I can figure out the adding text), and then how to push the frame back into the video?  If you have some idea, or know of a tutorial, I would appreciate it..

Comment: Did you go through the AVFoundation framework documentation?

Comment: Why would you want to save it as a modified video as long as every time it plays it has the same transparent view over the top? Editing video is CPU intensive and hence battery depleting on a mobile device.

Comment: iPhone already has video editing capability, as well as a complete iMovie suite for iPhone, so I don't see how adding text to frames is more taxing....

Comment: I didn't say it was more taxing, I questioned why your app needs to do it. Video editing software already available is intended to allow for a large array of editing needs, but are largely intended for small sequence edits, cutting, segues and the like. You are looking to change every frame of a video systematically when there would appear from your original question to be no need, hence why I am asking for clarification, the more information you provide the more help others can be, if you don't want the help of others, I'd suggest not asking.

Comment: I am also looking for the same. But getting anything good

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to do this on a frame by frame basis. AVFoundation supports subtitles since iOS 4.0.

You could for instance create a [AVMutableComposition](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVMutableComposition_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and then add a subtitle track on top of your video. AVMediaTypeSubtitle is the type for subtitles (or AVMediaTypeClosedCaption for closed captions). You can then feed the composition to either a player or a [AVAssetWriter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetWriter_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Saves you all the trouble.

Comment: I'am interested about your solution, but I didn't find out how to set the text of "subtitle" using "AVMediaTypeSubtitle". Could you please give a example? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

According to what you said, here's a example you can learn.

[image]

As you can see from above picture, you can add border, Overlay, Subtitle, anything you want to a video.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos

Answer (score 1):

You can Edit  video through AvFoundation Framework...

Here is an Example..

var assetTrack = AVAsset.assetWithURL(filePath1) as! AVURLAsset
        var mutableComposition = AVMutableComposition()

```
    // Step - 1  pass url to  avasset

    // video

    var compositionVideoTrack = AVMutableCompositionTrack()
    compositionVideoTrack = mutableComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())


    var assetVideoTrack = assetTrack.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0] as! AVAssetTrack
    compositionVideoTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero , assetTrack.duration), ofTrack: assetVideoTrack, atTime: kCMTimeZero, error: nil)

    // audio

    var compositionAudioTrack = AVMutableCompositionTrack()
    compositionAudioTrack = mutableComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())

    var assetAudioTrack = assetTrack.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)[0] as! AVAssetTrack
    compositionAudioTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero , assetTrack.duration), ofTrack: assetAudioTrack, atTime: kCMTimeZero, error: nil)

    var videoAssetOrientation_: UIImageOrientation = .Up
    var isVideoAssetPortrait_: Bool = false

    var videoTransform: CGAffineTransform = assetTrack.preferredTransform



    var videosize = CGSize()
    videosize = assetVideoTrack.naturalSize

    var parentLayer = CALayer()
    var videoLayer = CALayer()
    var textLayer = CALayer()

    parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videosize.width, videosize.height)
    videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videosize.width, videosize.height)
    textLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videosize.width, videosize.height)

    parentLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)

    if drawingView.image != nil
    {
        var drawingLayer = CALayer()
        drawingLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videosize.width, videosize.height)
        drawingLayer.contents = drawingView.image.CGImage

        var image = UIImage()
        parentLayer.addSublayer(drawingLayer)

    }


    var textV = UIView()
    textV.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    textV.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    textV.frame = CGRectMake(self.captureView.frame.size.width, 0, self.captureView.frame.size.width, self.captureView.frame.size.height)

    var textL = UILabel()
    textL = textShowOnPreview
    textV.addSubview(textL)

    if textL != ""
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(textV.bounds.size)
        textV.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
        var image1: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        if ( TextAnimation == "")
        {
            textLayer.contents = image1.CGImage
            parentLayer.addSublayer(textLayer)
        }

        else if  ( TextAnimation == "flip")
        {

            var overlayer1 = CALayer()
            overlayer1.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
            let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
            overlayer1.contents = image1.CGImage
            overlayer1.masksToBounds = true
            overlayer1.frame = CGRectMake(videosize.width/2-300, videosize.height/2 - 400, videosize.width,videosize.width);
            var   animation : CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
            animation.duration=5.0;
            animation.repeatCount=5;
            animation.autoreverses = true;
            // rotate from 0 to 360
            animation.fromValue = 0
            animation.toValue = (2.0 * M_PI);
            animation.beginTime = AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero;
            overlayer1.addAnimation(animation, forKey:"rotation")
            [parentLayer .addSublayer(overlayer1)]

        }
        else if ( TextAnimation == "fade")
        {

                       //opacity
            var overlayer1 = CALayer()
            overlayer1.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
            overlayer1.contents = image1.CGImage
            overlayer1.masksToBounds = true

            overlayer1.frame = CGRectMake(videosize.width/2 - 300,  videosize.height/2 - 100 , videosize.width+20, videosize.width);
            var   animation : CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
            animation.duration = 2.0;
            animation.repeatCount = 3;
            animation.autoreverses = true;
            // rotate from 0 to 360

            animation.fromValue = 0.5;
            animation.toValue = 1.0;
            animation.beginTime = AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero;

            overlayer1.addAnimation(animation, forKey:"scale")
            [parentLayer .addSublayer(overlayer1)]

        }
        else if ( TextAnimation == "bounce")
        {
            var overlayer1 = CALayer()

            var bounce : CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation (keyPath:"position.y");
            overlayer1.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
            overlayer1.contents = image1.CGImage
            overlayer1.masksToBounds = true
            overlayer1.frame = CGRectMake(videosize.width/2 - 300,  videosize.height/2 - 100 , videosize.width, videosize.width);
            bounce.duration = 1.0;
            bounce.fromValue =  overlayer1.frame.origin.y

            bounce.toValue =  overlayer1.frame.origin.y - 100
            bounce.repeatCount = 10
            bounce.autoreverses = true;
            overlayer1.addAnimation(bounce, forKey: "y")

            var animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
            animation.toValue = NSNumber(float: 0.9)
            animation.duration = 1.0
            animation.repeatCount = 10;
            animation.autoreverses = true
            overlayer1.addAnimation(animation, forKey: nil)
             [parentLayer .addSublayer(overlayer1)]

        }

    }

    var mutableVideoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    mutableVideoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
    mutableVideoComposition.renderSize = videosize

    mutableVideoComposition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, inLayer: parentLayer)


    var passThroughInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    passThroughInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, mutableComposition.duration)


    var passThroughLayerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction()


    // video

    var assestVideoMutableCompositionVideo = mutableComposition.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0] as! AVAssetTrack
    passThroughLayerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: assestVideoMutableCompositionVideo)



    if isVideoAssetPortrait_ == false
    {

        var FirstAssetScaleFactor: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1)

        passThroughLayerInstruction.setTransform(CGAffineTransformConcat(assetVideoTrack.preferredTransform, FirstAssetScaleFactor), atTime: kCMTimeZero)

    }


    passThroughInstruction.layerInstructions = [passThroughLayerInstruction]
    mutableVideoComposition.instructions = [passThroughInstruction]

    let documentsURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0] as! NSURL
    let filePath = documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("NewWatermarkedVideo.mov") as NSURL


    var fileManager:NSFileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    fileManager.removeItemAtURL(filePath, error: nil)

   var exporter: AVAssetExportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mutableComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality)
    exporter.videoComposition = mutableVideoComposition
    exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
    exporter.outputURL = filePath
    exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
    self.captureView.addSubview(textShowOnPreview)

    exporter.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler({() -> Void in

        println(exporter.status)

        if  exporter.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Completed
        {


            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in




                MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDsForView(self.view, animated: true)

                self.topicSelectedImage.highlighted = false
                self.timelineSelectedImage.highlighted = false
                self.selectCat = ""
                self.postView.hidden = false

            })

            println("Completed")
            self.mediaData =  NSData(contentsOfURL:filePath, options: nil, error: nil)!


            var err: NSError? = nil
            var asset = AVURLAsset(URL: filePath, options: nil)
            var imgGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
            var cgImage = imgGenerator.copyCGImageAtTime(CMTimeMake(0, 30), actualTime: nil, error: &err)
            var uiImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgImage)!
            self.videoThumbData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(uiImage, 0.1)

            var assetTrack = AVAsset.assetWithURL(filePath) as! AVURLAsset
            self.videoTime = Int(CMTimeGetSeconds(assetTrack.duration)) + 3

            println(self.videoTime)


        }
        else if exporter.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Cancelled
        {


        }
        else if exporter.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Failed
        {


        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who do want to edit a movie frame by frame, use [AVReaderWriter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/ReaderWriter/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011124). Though its an OS X Apple sample code, AVFoundation is available on both platforms with little changes.